# Detect Browser tab close event Clear php session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to detect browser tab close and clear session using AJAX call.

`window.onbeforeunload` only detects on page reload.

Comment: I think you need to do a AJAX call on unload. But the server needs to respond before the window actualy closes.

Comment: **onbeforunload** is not a proper event for your objective because it execute each time when you leave your page.
please follow https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/ to get your objective.